# Differency between @PreAuthorize and @Secure on Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Using bundle  [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/annotations#secure) .

Comment: The difference maybe only that PreAuthorize will let you define an expression (possibly complex), while Secure it's a shortcut and works only with roles. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[@PreAuthorize](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Annotation/PreAuthorize.php),**

It allows you add your own expression method,

```
@PreAuthorize("myMethod('class', 'perm')")
```

For example, when using ACL permissions you can add something like,

```
@PreAuthorize("isGranted('myObject', 'CREATE')")
```

**[@Secure](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Annotation/Secure.php),**

It just allows you define who is allowed to invoke a method based on user roles.

```
@Secure(roles="ROLE_XXXX")
```

Comment: That is what I tought, I just wasn't sure if I was missing something because if this is the case then Secure is just a shortcut.